# How do I get the type object of a genericized Enum? eg: EnumSet.noneOf(<huh?>)

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic type that is parameterized on some Enum, declared like this:

```
public class FlagsField<T extends Enum<T>> {

    private EnumSet<T> _flagSet;

    public FlagsField() {
        _flagSet = EnumSet.<T>noneOf( /* what goes here? */ );
    }

    ...
}
```

I want to initialize _flagsField in the constructor as above, but can't figure out for the life of me what the right parameter to the noneOf method is.  It needs to be of type `Class<T>`. If this weren't a generic, you'd use `MyFooEnumType.class` here, but `T.class` is not valid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've run into [type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).  Your constructor is going to need to look like:

```
public FlagsField(Class<T> enumClass) {
    _flagSet = EnumSet.<T>noneOf(enumClass);
}
```

Comment: EnumSet needs to know about the type of the enum. For instance, complementOf will need to find all the enum constants of the type.

Comment: Java compiles just one version of the code for your generic class; the code doesn't have any compile time knowledge of the type parameter.

The JDK implementers faced this same issue; this is why EnumSet.noneOf() requires the class argument.  You aren't going to be able to do better than they did.

Comment: I think the generic parameter is not necessary in the method call. `EnumSet.noneOf(enumClass)` would work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this trick in your constructor: (see [Generic Data Access Objects](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects), section "Preparing DAOs with lookup")

```
enumClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

But I believe this code only works when the class is sub-classed and an instance of the sub-class executes it.