# How can I construct an EnumSet of generic varargs?

Tags: java, generics

Assume I want to do something like the following:

```
public static <V> Set<V> setOf(V... elem)
{
    Set<V> set = null;  
    if (elem[0] instanceof Enum)
        set = Sets.newEnumSet(elem, elem[0].getClass());  OR
        set = EnumSet.<V>noneOf(elem[0].getClass());
    return set;
}
```

Neither of these, or several other variations, seem to work.  Can someone explain to me what's going on?  I have looked at [How do I get the type object of a genericized Enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607250/how-do-i-get-the-type-object-of-a-genericized-enum-eg-enumset-noneofhuh) and some other similar questions, but I still can't get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to make sure the type `V` is restricted to be an enum type; you can do this by specifiying that `V` must `extends Enum<V>`.

Then, you will need to provide the `Class` of the enum type. Due to type-erasure, you won't be able to derive it at run-time. This is needed because, to construct a new empty `EnumSet`, you need to specify the type of the elements.

Finally, you have several ways to create the set, but the simplest might be to use the Stream API:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <V extends Enum<V>> Set<V> setOf(Class<V> enumClass, V... elem) {
    return Arrays.stream(elem).collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> EnumSet.noneOf(enumClass)));
}
```

Note that if you can guarantee that there will be at least 1 element, you could use `EnumSet.copyOf(Arrays.asList(elem))` without the need to pass the class.

Comment: For reasons that don't appear in the simplified example given, I can't declare V to extend Enum<V>; that's why I checked to see if enum[0] was an instance of Enum.
I knew that type erasure would lose the type of V, which is why I didn't try for set=Sets.newEnumSet(V.class).

Comment: @EQvan I suggest you edit your post with the restrictions then... because why are trying to construct an `EnumSet<V>` is `V` may not be an enum? You have to have the type to create an empty EnumSet.

Comment: I can ensure that there is always at least 1 element, and EnumSet.copyOf(Arrays.asList(elem)) is exactly where I started... but this gives me a "bounds mismatch" error that I don't completely understand.

Comment: @EQvan Because `V` may not be an enum type. The compiler cannot guess it, you have to tell it by specifying the restrictions on `V`.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler know the type of the actual object passed into the method?

Comment: @EQvan With `V` as-is, you're saying your function accepts any type, so it would be allowed at compile-time to call it with a non enum type, whatever how you are actually calling it. But this can't work since `EnumSet` expects the type of be an enum type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118116/discussion-between-eqvan-and-tunaki).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't bound the generic parameter to `V extends Enum<V>`, you can make compilable code as follows:

```
public <V> Set<V> setOf(V... elem) {
    Set<V> set = null;
    if (elem[0].getClass().isEnum()) {
        set = (Set<V>) EnumSet.copyOf((Collection<Enum>)Arrays.asList(elem)) ;
    }
    return set;
}
```

Of course there are unsafe cast warnings.

---

I also changed the check of the type to:

```
if (elem[0].getClass().isEnum())
```

which IMHO is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, which may look slightly weird, but also works nicely:

```java
public static EnumSet<MyEnum> setOf(MyEnum... elems) {
    return elems.length > 0 ?
        EnumSet.of(elems[0], elems) : EnumSet.noneOf(MyEnum.class);
}
```

Comment: This is not generic, which is what the question is asking about